# Is combining strings to make up the name of a pre-existing Control possible?

Tags: c#

I have a fair amount of Button controls that are dynamically created at runtime. The amount of these controls is user-determined, and they are given 'incremental' names.

For example, the buttons are arranged in a two dimensional 'table-like' format, and are named as such:

```
Name:(XAxisNo)(YAxisNo)
Box11
Box12
Box13
```

These are all public, and I want to edit them from a void that gets called by clicking another part of the interface.

Initially I (foolishly, in hindsight) thought that something like this could work:

```
for(int x = 1; x!= chunkCountX; x++)
{
     for(int y=1;y!= chunkCountY; y++)
     {
       ["Box" + x + y].BackgroundImage = presetImageVar;
     }
```

But that didn't work, so I tried something similar to this:

```
Button currentButton = new Button();
for(int x = 1; x!= chunkCountX; x++)
{
    for(int y=1;y!= chunkCountY; y++)
    {
        currentButton.Name = "Box" + x + y;
        currentButton.BackgroundImage = presetImageVar;
        currentButton.BackgroundImage = presetImageVar;
    }
}
```

My question is: Is it possible to build the name of an existing Control out of variables that I can then interface with the properties, or would it have to be done some other way?

Comment: If the name is only so you can reference the control, there's a lot of mileage in defining your own collection e.g. chunkButtons[x,y]  PS that code, was not adding the new button a typo?

Comment: No, it wasn't a type. I noticed by defining it like that it would give me prompts to change the Properties. However, when I realised what I was doing (and how tired I was), I understood that what I was doing wouldn't reference existing objects - but rather create new ones.

Comment: Ah knocking up a collection of existing objects needs some find by code code anyway, so following my suggestion would be of dubious value. Another option would be to use the tag property of the button to store your x and Y locations instead of messing about with names, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
["Box" + x + y].BackgroundImage
```

Try:

```
this.Controls["Box" + x + y].BackgroundImage
```

You can access your `Controls` by it's name.Here, **this** represents your `Form`.If your buttons are direct child control of the Form, this should work.Otherwise you need to access control collection of your actual container instead of your Form.

```
for(int x = 1; x < chunkCountX; x++)
{
     for(int y=1; y < chunkCountY; y++)
     {
         string btnName = "Box" + x + y;
         if(this.Controls.ContainsKey(btnName)) 
                this.Controls[btnName].BackgroundImage = presetImageVar;
     }
}
```

Here is another solution with `LINQ` which gets all the buttons in nested controls that has the name starts with `"Box"` and change the `BackgroundImage`:

```
var buttons = this.Controls.OfType<Control>()
                   .SelectMany(x => x.Controls.OfType<Button>()
                                     .Where(x => x.Name.StartsWith("Box")));
foreach(var button in buttons)
      button.BackgroundImage = presetImageVar;
```

Comment: This gives me 'System.NullReferenceException', with Additional Information of 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

Comment: where is your buttons ?

Comment: If the buttons are in a container e.g. a panel, then it would be something like this.Controls['buttonPanel'].Controls["Box" + x + y].BackgroundImage

Comment: Or, just `panelName.Controls[btnName]`

Comment: Aye,  as long as the panel isn't dynamically created as well. :(

Comment: You're right! It's in a Panel and I can't believe I didn't mention it. The Panel, however, is not dynamically generated. So I shall try that now!

Comment: Right, it was in a panel called 'GroupReferencePanel', and when I swapped 'this' out for 'GridReferencePanel', it worked!

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 1):

If all dynamically created buttons have name starting with `Box` and you want to update them all, then you can use LINQ to select such buttons and then update them in a loop:

```
var buttons = Controls.OfType<Button>().Where(b => b.Name.StartsWith("Box"));

foreach(var button in buttons)
    button.BackgroundImage = presetImageVar;
```